# Getting Error - "Username and Pool information are required" in Nest App When ChangePassword is Called

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, amazon-cognito

I was Trying with NestJS and Cognito and Getting the below Error -

```
"message": "Username and Pool information are required."
```

The **Controller** I have Built is -

```
@Patch('changePassword')
  async changePassword(@Body() user: ChangePasswordDto) {
    try {
      return await this.authService.changePassword(user);
    } catch (e) {
      throw new HttpException(e.message, e.status);
    }
  }
```

The **service** for the change Password is -

```
changePassword(user: ChangePasswordDto) {
    const { username, oldPassword, newPassword } = user;
    const userData = {
      Username: username,
      Pool: this.userPool,
    };
    const cognitoUser = new CognitoUser(userData);
    cognitoUser.getSession((err: any, result: any) => {
      if (result) {
        cognitoUser.changePassword(
          oldPassword,
          newPassword,
          (err: any, result: any) => {
            if (result) {
              return result;
            } else {
              throw new HttpException(err, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            }
          },
        );
      } else {
        throw new HttpException(err, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
      }
    });
  }
```

The **User pool** has been initialized at *constructor* like -

```
this.userPool = new CognitoUserPool({
    UserPoolId: this.authConfig.userPoolId,
    ClientId: this.authConfig.clientId,
});
```

I am able to successfully login and getting some Response like this -

```
{
  "idToken": {
    "jwtToken": "eyJraWQiOiJKNkNGlheUBnbWFpbC5jb20ifQ.rhgZAC8SGTVVsM21V6ktWwf-2dMDksU9r8NOuWrPO7HwaQuVDmyXU2_mJOI53D3zP3CrpGXQWadQnv8gVmYtxTnLExEc4z1X2s9M9_XkSAlCEeD1uKNMfjvq7M6JPnxZqb1X6YoLFBmCUOVK_uR8VPpqfF45g39yLblHWxK83ouOtZaPeTmD1p_AEhTLahJF3aIOQ",
    "payload": {
      "sub": "2aed3574932f",
      "email_verified": true,
      "iss": "https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/xxxx",
      "cognito:username": "xxxxxxxxrrrrrrr",
      "origin_jti": "bc0b-8dbe8330d357",
      "aud": "e3r13314134",
      "event_id": "adcd-d97bbc385350",
      "token_use": "id",
      "auth_time": 1670939555,
      "exp": 1670943155,
      "iat": 1670939555,
      "jti": "r3434414-a25a071ef805",
      "email": "xxxx@gmail.com"
    }
  },
  "refreshToken": {
    "token": "hzQQ3k6rQpOG4uHcQ9oplMiW3VeyiIHJzOelzN-PBclYpdS3QeaJ7jBJwcYMMJEHFMUHL30FoQoGp3m466Ej9ldLjRepqHO1ozoCfZb0K8xQmvvaPmpmkuC8LTJzAa5hd3-li7jd6GNHB1UyBuyQpc4JifcGuMvjPbYLiCumF4Zw0TiUzfqh3qaB1nsfV6i8qaGsY5BfOypUdysFijNHkDZFF5kX3K_WwVq0hPflFNRKiYpK7MEN0kIiH9u6s7-BjYloaknCZYdClpdZpXhoRwE_LkQKBR7eu1bNQ3d32t5NGCuwT_APIhjp4q1XvkG4b2NeIuRTn_KGP7SQJ5zE7_Ad4DdN39bFAn8Ij0r2t0HjBPlMpL_y-S0HJLfDRnH-dxsmuMN08EcFaYQRNVdxiQukOh-3goF2qb-sZEpA4srSehjhklR8cwA5zA8-bxJYvPHHhXwGcA34QxTdWiteWhbowGTf3RxnVvK7opR__Ega28j7UXLMPyMrIGX5zzTmSPEsawI4xLFhbwxyK4tFVg_FF4oDTUYV9cca1dleGLSfTUt4WdDQcZt0zDhz-0UlIsd3SkHnMQWQNa2iSwZ8r_61XZMcP7cAP1242C6x_vyGZ7D1TR2L6KC6LUAMEcidQebjcsxBFBiPLnDE3ZCdyCpLXz47wJs8hRXnIDLVq6rit4eMtw3SQbShPFS2hrZHF-GzkcosPCM3Y-tDpknvLDA4EkkT7KiPfBPj_v_53DvCFRGhlkD1NZt0nkEZWSc9_hFveLRgwF69uDclLYcX1Gr-0TpnXraw1QPXtrFrGAhIBuhQ42DgiJzzhpkoEe-ldH83bQMxKaR3ua6VQ2guya-oF4_92za3UbhJ5QX4Y2MVrI0wKu3CJCWK5jXgFV-NixBcFbdcONZ_fZTIKO6o6eoC3LEVGp2fbGiEf.sFvhsM093-EIewHbk0ubIQ"
  },
  "accessToken": {
    "jwtToken": "OmuTMJ55unT-f1Il7v-znnlt7MCywL3-Ro3tytZvkSMGOzLIhL4vJJsdwSwgIALkU2Kp8m_-8HvMElt-k4vHqVhAvfLdOMq288dAu6u_9Mgg5KUGedYcEqWh2BF8C14Q8g",
    "payload": {
      "sub": "afqwrqeqweqweqweqw-bf05-2aed3574932f",
      "iss": "https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/xxxxxx",
      "client_id": "qeqweqwe4123412422ldt0a1jl3d2k",
      "origin_jti": "bc0b-8dbe8330d357",
      "event_id": "adcd-d97bbc385350",
      "token_use": "access",
      "scope": "aws.cognito.signin.user.admin",
      "auth_time": 1670939555,
      "exp": 1670943155,
      "iat": 1670939555,
      "jti": "810f-0f8a2ce85d05",
      "username": "xxxxxx"
    }
  },
  "clockDrift": 0
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this By the Following Snippets -

**Controller**

```
@Post('changePassword')
  @UsePipes(ValidationPipe)
  async changePassword(
    @Body() authChangePasswordUserDto: AuthChangePasswordUserDto,
  ) {
    const result = await this.awsCognitoService.changeUserPassword(
      authChangePasswordUserDto,
    );
    if (result == 'SUCCESS') {
      return { status: 'Password Changed Successfully' };
    }
  }
```

**Service**

```
async changeUserPassword(
    authChangePasswordUserDto: AuthChangePasswordUserDto,
  ) {
    const { email, currentPassword, newPassword } = authChangePasswordUserDto;

    const userData = {
      Username: email,
      Pool: this.userPool,
    };

    const authenticationDetails = new AuthenticationDetails({
      Username: email,
      Password: currentPassword,
    });

    const userCognito = new CognitoUser(userData);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      userCognito.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
        onSuccess: () => {
          userCognito.changePassword(
            currentPassword,
            newPassword,
            (err, result) => {
              if (err) {
                reject(err);
                return;
              }
              resolve(result);
            },
          );
        },
        onFailure: (err) => {
          reject(err);
        },
      });
    });
  }
```

Also, Please make sure to make the changes in your User Pool in *AWS* to login with your **email** as **username**.